# "more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'" on Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, android-build

I'm getting an error when trying to build my ionic app for android. It throws an error: `Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'` and I can't figure out what combination of plugins is causing it. What plugins are causing the issue and what can I do about it? Thanks!

Output of `ionic plugin list`:

```
cc.fovea.cordova.purchase 3.11.0 "Purchase"
com.google.playservices 21.0.0 "Google Play Services for Android"
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.5.8 "PushPlugin"
com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect 0.11.2 "Facebook"
com.verso.cordova.clipboard 0.1.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-camera 1.2.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.2.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 2.1.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.2.0 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.0 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.0.1-dev "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
org.apache.cordova.globalization 0.3.4 "Globalization"
twitter-connect-plugin 0.4.0 "Twitter Connect"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woo! I was able to fix it.

1. Create a `build-extras.gradle` file in the same folder as your build.gradle.
2. Fill it with this:

   `configurations {
     all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
     all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-analytics'
   }`

The second line is related to this error, the first line fixes a similar issue.

Comment: You may also look at this fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775891/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-using-co/34776219#34776219

Answer (score 0):

Run `./gradlew :app:dependencies` and see which packages are using `com.google.android.gms`. Then exclude it one or more dependency:

```
compile('some_package') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'some_module'
}
```

Comment: I get `./gradlew: No such file or directory`

Comment: Use `gradlew.bat` if you're using Windows or check the permissions/path if you're using Unix.

Comment: Ok. Figured out I had to move into the android folder `cd platforms/android` then I was able to run `./gradlew :app:dependencies` and got and error `Project 'app' not found in root project 'android'.`

Comment: `app` is basically the name of the module that contains your code. That's the default name, but you might have changed it. When you open AndroidStudio, under the project tab, modules are the top most expandable items. You can get the name there.